# How do I animate a jQuery function's variable on a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation, blur

I have an image (inside a div `#respirando`) blurred using [Foggy.js](http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/).

I want to animate that blur function continuously on and off. I assume this would mean being able to control the `blurRadius` variable using a loop function. I have tried using `.animate()` but I am not sure if I can animate a jQuery property like this and what the syntax would consist of.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#respirando').foggy();

    $('#respirando').foggy({
        blurRadius: 6,          // In pixels.
        opacity: 1,             // Falls back to a filter for IE.
        cssFilterSupport: true  // Use "-webkit-filter" where available.
    }); 
});
```

Maybe `$('#respirando').foggy.animate`?
Or `$('#respirando').animate`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `blurRadius` is not a property of your image, just a parameter that foggy uses, and therefore not eligible for use with `.animate`.

It seems the purpose of foggy is to give support to browsers that don't support `-webkit-filter: blur`. If you don't care about that, you could not use foggy and then you could just apply `-webkit-filter: blur` to your image and use `$('#respirando > img').animate()`.

Another option is to create a timer loop and on each iteration destroy foggy then recreate it with blurRadius incremented maybe.

Edit: @3dgoo has shown an example of using CSS animation to apply blur as well:

```
img {
  width: 300px;
}

.blur {
  animation: blur 5s infinite;
  animation: blur 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}

@keyframes blur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is a demo of using css animation and css blur to achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/93o22x7r/ . Feel free to use this in your answer if you would like.